# How to send exact packet over TCP client

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I am trying to send a specific TCP packet to a server but it doesn't seem like it is sending the right data. How should I go about this

I have tried StreamWriter class. Using the NetworkStream. Sending Bytes, sending ASCII and sending text.

```cs
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("game_server_ip", port);

NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

writer.WriteLine("....T..hello");
writer.Flush();
```

I am trying to send this exact packet:

```
00 00 00 0c 54 00 05 68 65 6c 6c 6f
```

Which translates to the text above
This is also the raw bytes:
`0000000c54000568656c6c6f`

The expected result should mean that the ingame chat should send a message saying hello. I have made sure the connection is up and running and it is. Also have tried sending the packet using Wireshark and WPE Pro and they work fine. (I got this packet from snifing)

Comment: "_Which translates to the text above_". No. And neither does the text string `"....T..hello"` translate to the byte values you want to have... The dot character `.` is not a zero byte. Nor is the `.` character the value 0x0c or 0x05. Do you really think that if you type some dots in a string that it will sometimes turn into 0x00, then sometimes to 0x0c, and then sometimes to 0x05, and not just sometimes but also just at the right positions because... ...magic? Look up any ASCII table to see what the value of the `.` character really is...

Comment: I may be wrong, and am unsure as to how wireshark presents the data but that looks a lot like the HEX representation of the data. Which when converted seems to equal to "Tel" - https://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter

Comment: @Hozikimaru, "_Which when converted seems to equal to "Tel"_" No, it doesn't. Where did you get that idea from? Doing random stuff on a random website without knowing what that website actually _really_ does just gives random, meaningless "results". Clearly the bytes at the positions corresponding to "T" and "hello" are just the ASCII values (or UTF-8 values, if you will) of the respective characters. There is no "Tel" thing in what the OP presented here... o.O???

Answer (score 0):

For TCP you will need to connect to the remote endpoint.

Check this example out [Example](http://www.csharp-examples.net/socket-send-receive/)

Comment: Need to do some debugging in here. Find out packet is being sent.

Comment: I know the packet is being sent because when I try to send it, the text box pops up on the game but does not send anything. Which maybe means I am not sending the right data.

Comment: @shtabbbe So I need to know exactly what is being sent. Can you use a sniffer to find out what's being sent?